# Samsung S4 Recover a Photo On Internal Memory Without Root

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I need to recover a photo from the internal memory of a Samsung Galaxy S4. The problem is that the S4 uses the Media Transfer Protocol (MTP), so Windows cannot access the device as a disk. So almost every recovery program cannot read from the phone's internal memory.

I have watched many Youtube videos and tutorials, but they always seem to need Root privileges. I cannot root the device, since it's been lent to me.

I have tried on Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: The shorter answer in this case is that you can't, in case anyone else has the same problem. If you don't have a low level access to the internal memory you can't recover files from it.